# Use custom HTML elements for JSON key variables after recursive loop javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I have a JSON object that I'm able to loop through on click which I use to display in HTML to the end user.  Currently the display is very generic and puts everything in a P tag.

What I'd like to do is build custom elements depending on its key as well as not show items if its key value is null.  So far this is what I'm working with:

```
var obj = {
    "x": 1409529600000,
    "y": 730,
    "pf": [
        {
            "sd": "this is some text",
            "ld": "here guy"
        },
        {
            "sd": "here is more yo",
            "ld": "ld over here"
        }
    ],
    "nf": [
        {
            "sd": "im in the nf array",
            "ld": "Hi mom"
        },
        {
            "sd": "me too!",
            "ld": "Where am i"
        }
    ],
    "t": [
        "here is a tip",
        "how about the other tip"
    ]
};

(function(){
    document
      .getElementById('myObj')
      .addEventListener("click",  showObjData);
}());

function buildData(content) {
    var data = document.createElement('p');
    data.innerHTML = content;
    return data;
}

function goThroughObj(obj) {
    var htmlObj,
        property;
    for (property in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if (typeof obj[property] === "object") {
                goThroughObj(obj[property]);
            } else {
                document
                  .getElementById('showObj')
                  .appendChild(buildData(obj[property]));
            }
        }
    }    
}

 function showObjData() {
    var key,
        title,
        element = document.getElementById('showObj');

     // clear innerHTML in case user click more than once
     element.innerHTML='';

     for (key in obj) {
         // skip anything that is not an array, ie: x, y
        if (obj[key] instanceof Array) {
            title = '<br/>From ' + key + ' : ';
            element.appendChild(buildData(title));
            // use recursive function 
            // to go through each keys/properties
            goThroughObj(obj[key]);
        }
    }
};
```

And here is the jfiddle to go along with it http://jsfiddle.net/kzcm32g8/6/

As you can see each entry gets placed inside a P tag.  Instead what I'd like is something more customized per key.  So for instance it would look more like:

- if pf exists bind to `<h2>` with custom string
- if sd exists within pf bind value to `<p class="first">`
- if ld exists within pf bind value  to `<p class="second">`

---

- if nf exists bind to `<h2>` with custom string
- if sd exists within pf bind value to `<p class="first">`
- if ld exists within pf bind value  to `<p class="second">`

---

- if t exists bind to `<h2>` with custom string
- bind array values to `<p>`

---

The idea is to allow me to assign the returned data to a template that I have styled.  If values are null I would just exclude them from that template.

Comment: Doing this sort of data binding is made much easier using JavaScript MVC libraries like Angular.

Comment: I totally agree, however for this particular case the use of a library isn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alexis mentioned, there are libraries available that can make this type of thing easier. If you just need a quick and dirty jQuery solution you can just check for each key you care about. If you find a key, it's vaule will be an array of objects. Loop through that array checking each object for your other keys and just build up an html string as you go then set the string to a div's `html`

```js
var obj = {
    "x": 1409529600000,
    "y": 730,
    "pf": [
        {
            "sd": "this is some text",
            "ld": "here guy"
        },
        {
            "sd": "here is more yo",
            "ld": "ld over here"
        }
    ],
    "nf": [
        {
            "sd": "im in the nf array",
            "ld": "Hi mom"
        },
        {
            "sd": "me too!",
            "ld": "Where am i"
        }
    ],
    "t": [
        "here is a tip",
        "how about the other tip"
    ]
};

var myHTML = '';
// check if `obj` has a key named `pf`
if (obj['pf']) {
  // it does, so make a header for `pf`
    myHTML += '<h2>From pf :</h2><br>';
    // `obj['pf']` is an array of objects
    // loop through each object in the array
    $.each(obj['pf'], function(i, e) {
        // ccheck if the current object has a key named `sd`
        if (e['sd']) {
            // it does, make a `p` tag with `first` class 
            // and insert the value for key 'sd' from the current object
            myHTML += '<p class="first">' + e['sd'] + '</p><br>';
        }
        if (e['ld']) {
            // it does, make a `p` tag with `second` class 
            // and insert the value for key 'ld' from the current object
            myHTML += '<p class="second">' + e['ld'] + '</p><br>';
        }
    });
}
// same as above just using the 'nf' key
if (obj['nf']) {
    myHTML += '<h2>From nf :</h2><br>';
   
    $.each(obj['nf'], function(i, e) {

        if (e['sd']) {
            myHTML += '<p class="first">' + e['sd'] + '</p><br>';
        }
        if (e['ld']) {
            myHTML += '<p class="second">' + e['ld'] + '</p><br>';
        }
    });
}
if (obj['t']) {
    myHTML += '<h2>From t :</h2>';
    // here `obj['t']` is just an array of strings not an array of objects
    // just loop through the array inserting the value of each index into a `p` tag
    $.each(obj['t'], function(i, e) {
        myHTML += '<p>' + e + '</p>';
    });
}
$('#test').html(myHTML);
```

```css
.first{
  background-color:#cccccc;
  
  }

.second{
  background-color:#eeeeee;
  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```